# Pronunciation of Trapezoid?

Tags: pronunciation

How do you pronounce Trapezoid?

[Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_English) answer preferred.

Comment: [Dictionary reference](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/trapezoid)

Comment: And according to the same reference the US may have a preferred pronunciation http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/trapezoid and compare it with _trapezium_ which has only one pronunciation in both UK/US http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/trapezium

Comment: @Andrew never knew of this great resource. I was always used to search Google, GTranslate and Wikipedia. Thanks! BTW, you can delete the question instead of just closing it and allowing it to keep on reputing me with downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ODE gives two pronunciations:

> 'trapɪzↄɪd
>
> trə'piːzↄɪd

I find the first one to be more common than te second pronunciation.